# Flash uploader - crossdomain issues

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml, file-upload, yui-uploader

I'm using YUI file uploader based on flash, and the flash requests host/crossdomain.xml file.  I'm requesting localhost and it requires this file. I was using this before and I have never had this problem and I've never had this file on my server.

I've never used any adobe technologies, could please anybody tell me if it is possible to turn it off somehow ?

The problem is that I can't have the file on my server, at least at root location...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, it depends from where you get the uploader.swf

If uploader.swf is loaded from the server you are requesting, then no crossdomain.xml is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your inability to add files to your web server root location, there are ways around it (documented at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html ), although I believe it would require a modified version of uploader.swf compiled to look for a crossdomain.xml at a different location on your server, and your server would have to be configured to serve a custom header telling the flash player it's okay to accept that file.